# PLESK Change webmail and mailserver URL

Tags: dns, plesk, webmail

Expect following PLESK Panel (12.5) with following domains:

```
maindomain.de (This is the hostname of the server)
customer1.de
customer2.de
```

The mail server is accessable via: `mail.[domain].de`
The webmail is accessable via: `webmail.[domain].de`

Is it possible to configure plesk, that all (maindomain, customer1, customer2) can access the mailserver via: `maindomain.de` (for all customers) and the webmail is also accessable via `maindomain.de`, `webmail.customer1.de` and `webmail.customer2.de`?

Can this be establish with the DNS or how can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the subdomains used for mail / webmail in the standard DNS template which can be found in `Tools & Settings` > `DNS Template`
Change all directives that contain `webmail` to a subdomain you want and save your changes.

[image: Preview]

---

All users should be able to access their mails from `maindomain.de`, at least this is working for me and I use a non-modified DNS template. As far as I know it is not possible to access the webmail client from the hostname domain (`webmail.maindomain.de`).

Comment: I think `webmail.maindomain.de` is not possible at all with Plesk but all other configurations can be made with the DNS templates.